# How to make sure validation for at least one section with Laravel validation

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I have a form with two sections **A** & **B**.

**A** has following fields.
   name,result

**B** has following fields.
   name1,result1

No i want to make sure that user fills at least one section to continue.

This is what i am trying to do.

```
$this->validate($request, [
               'name' => 'required',
               'result' => 'required',
               'name1' => 'required',
               'result1' => 'required'
 ]);
```

This validates both sections fields,but i want at least validate one section.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have two forms, one for every section, and two different actions that you post to?

Comment: yes it can be done,but is this possible what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option may be you can check if certain inputs are empty then make validation for each check,but it may not be a good approach.

You can try this as well,a much cleaner way.

```
  $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required_without:name1,result1',
                'result' => 'required_without:name1,result1',
                'name1' => 'required_without:name,result',
                'result1' => 'required_without:name,result'
             ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Required Without`:

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-with):

```
$input = $request->all();


    if(array_key_exists('name', $input) && array_key_exists('name1', $input) ){
        echo "Either of the section is required";
    }

    if(array_key_exists('result', $input) && array_key_exists('result1', $input) ){
        Echo"Either of the section is required";
    }

    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required_without:name1,result1',
        'result' => 'required_without:name1,result1',
        'name1' => 'required_without:name,result',
        'result1' => 'required_without:name,result'
    ];



    //validating request agianst rules
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    //if validation fails, will throw ValidationHttpException
    if($validator->fails()) {
        print_r($validator->errors());
    }else{
        echo "Validation passed";
    }
```

See if this works for you!! If not you can always use [custom validators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators).

Comment: By using your above code,through  syntax error,and by putting quotes around 'required_with:result', validation does not run

Comment: Updated. The only thing that you have to take care of the error message. `$validator->errors()` will gives you a multiple errors in `array`. You can just first error to show it to user, but again it's totally depend upon your requirement, you can also show all error messages.

Comment: Thank you for the effort,i will let you know if found any issue